# "Corner" vs. "nook"

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms

Are the nouns "corner" and "nook" synonymous? I just saw them employed in an enumeration as if they meant different things:

> ... has a funny shape, with ledges, corners, nooks,...

What are any differences between them?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the visual thesaurus? It can concisely give you a pretty good picture of word relationships

Comment: Reminds me of a Michael McIntyre joke... "I want the bits in the nooks, and the bobs in the crannies. I want this place *spic*."

Comment: @Bryan: The visual thesaurus? Where can I find it? Is it online? Is it a book, a software? Thanks.

Comment: @becko: http://www.visualthesaurus.com/

Comment: @Bryan: Wow. That link just made my day.

Comment: Glad to hear it--it's a find for logophiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is overlap, there is definitely domain unique to each. A nook could be an inside corner, but it connotes seclusion, and may denote "coziness." An outside corner could never be considered a nook. Also, a cubbyhole, or recess--which could have many or no corners in it (round nooks?)--would be a nook.

Answer (score 2):

A corner refers to a definite place where two walls, or surfaces, meet.
A nook refers to any small private space.