# Can 'nook' be used outside the saying 'nook and cranny'? Is it common?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

I'm looking for an English word that describes something comfortable: a safe space that one prefers to chill out in quiet solitude, and something that depicts a sentiment of familiarity.

I would like for the word to be informal, as per something you would say to a good friend of yours: 'And this is my little corner here.' 'Little corner' can be a good candidate but I'm looking for a single-word term.

By reading up on the thesaurus and the dictionary, I stumbled upon the word 'nook'.

So, I wonder, is the use of this word by itself appropriate? Or is it unidiomatic? I always used to hear it in the saying 'nook and cranny', and I wonder whether it's uncommon to have only 'nook' in a sentence.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28059/corner-vs-nook

Comment: Also related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71444/whats-the-difference-between-a-nook-and-a-cranny

Comment: The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84805/discussion-on-question-by-jd342-can-nook-be-used-outside-the-saying-nook-and).

Comment: Thank you for asking. Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.
Every Stack Exchange question should describe the asker's prior efforts to find an answer, and explain why the results were not adequate to answer the question. Some research is required on every question. This is called our research requirement. The link I gave above has more information about the research requirement.

Comment: Even cursory research will show that this question is about basic meaning and therefore really not a proper question for this forum.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can use *nook* without the *cranny*, for *nook* merely means "a corner or recess, especially one offering seclusion or security." (Oxford Dictionary) See [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nook) for sentence examples of *nook* by itself. As to whether it is common, that is something I wouldn't concern myself with. Commonality, or lack thereof, should not dictate whether something is used or not. Usage of language should be dictated only by communicative qualities; that is, whether the term or word in question adequately and succinctly communicates an idea, regardless of how old or common it is. This is just my opinion, however.

**INCIDENTAL ADDENDUM**:
My answer and I have been criticized by some, as you can see in the comments, so allow me to clarify: I am speaking solely about words that are in current use and are not considered “obsolete.” I do not think that one should use just any word; one still has to take the time to study the nuances of words. But people are too swayed by how common a word is as opposed to how expressive it is. Language’s sole purpose is for communicating, after all.

Comment: The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the answer, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid discussion or debate. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 24):

The [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) contains 75 instances of *nook* (I haven't checked *nooks*), although they're not all independent. E.g. three of the uses in a name are references to the same play, *Rookery Nook*.

Of those 75:

- 25 include the word *cranny* in close proximity.
- 17 are in names of houses, pubs, plays, streets, etc.
- 8 are in poetry (which I categorise apart because it tends to use rare words to fit metre and rhyme).
- 24 fit none of the above categories, so we could call them "general usage".
- And since that adds up to 74, I've lost one while I was sorting them into categories.

---

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has 1088 instances of *nook*, of which 208 have the word *cranny* within four words. (I didn't count these manually, but used the *collocates* feature of the search).

So in both corpora the word *nook* occurs more commonly **without** *cranny* than with.

As to commonality in general, the full frequency distribution of COCA is not available without payment, but the top two lemmata in the sample data are

```
Position  Word      Frequency
7309      attic     2711
17311     tearful   542
```

so it is maybe around the 12000th most common word in the corpus, and almost exactly twice as frequent as the perfectly common word *tearful*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84804/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-taylor-can-nook-be-used-outside-the-saying-nook).

Answer (score 15):

Out of curiosity, I searched both of Tolkien's *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* for "nook":

> [The cave] seemed quite a fair size, but not too large and mysterious. It had a dry floor and some comfortable **nooks**. At one end there was room for the ponies; and there they stood (mighty glad of the change) steaming, and champing in their nosebags.
>
> <sup>*The Hobbit*, Chapter 4: Over Hill And Under Hill, p.53</sup>
>
> A little later Frodo came out of the study to see how things were going on, and found [Lobelia] still about the place, investigating **nooks** and corners, and tapping the floors.
>
> <sup>*The Fellowship of the Rings*, Chapter 1: A Long-Expected Party, p. 57</sup>
>
> The westering sun was caught into clouds, and night came swiftly. They slept as well as they could for the cold, turn and turn about, in a **nook** among great jagged pinnacles of weathered rock; at least they were sheltered from the easterly wind.
>
> <sup>*The Two Towers*, Book Two, Chapter 1: The Taming of Sméagol, p. 227</sup>
>
> ‘We had better try a way back southwards along the line of the cliff, I
>   think,’ said Sam. ‘We might find some **nook** there, or even a cave or something.’ [...] They did not find the going any easier at the broken feet of the Emyn Muil. Nor did Sam find any **nook** or hollow to shelter in: only bare stony slopes frowned over by the cliff, which now rose again, higher and more sheer as they went back.
>
> <sup>*ibid.*, p. 237</sup>

Interestingly, *nook and cranny* doesn't appear at all. As to whether Tolkien's use of *nook* is "idiomatic", "appropriate" or "common", I'm not sure. I can say however that you'd be in good company.

Comment: Tolkien was a master writer and a philologist. If he used “nook” in such a fashion, then it must be a justified use. Glad you found this.

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed He did use plenty of archaic forms in his writings however. I would agree that these are strictly correct, but I cannot say whether they are idiomatic or common.

Comment: True, but as an experienced philologist, I’m sure Tolkien had a good idea of what is common or idiomatic. Just because others haven’t used it as he did does not mean that “nook” was used unidiomatically. And in his time, the “forms,” as you called them, were not archaic. To the [neophiliac](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neophiliac), contemporary reader it might be archaic, but not to me. Paleophobia is too common nowadays.

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed Tolkien last wrote 50 years ago, modern English hasn't changed that much. I can't go into his use of archaic words (_wain_) or constructs (_helms too they chose_) into the comments, but suffice to say that many of his works contained language that was not only considered archaic in his time, but specifically chosen because it was so. I do not however believe _nook_ to be unidiomatic: I merely meant that since English is a second language to me, I cannot confirm it.

Comment: Sorry, I got a little carried away. I thought you were talking about the style of his writing. I have read his entire works, so I get a little defensive when it comes to all things Tolkien. Of course, you’re right that he specifically chose archaic words. I meant no offense...

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed None taken, a quick look at [my profile on sfe.se](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48975/isanae?tab=answers) shows that we both share this same interest. Cheers!

Comment: For what it is worth, I am a native American English speaker and have a place in my home that I have always called the "nook" without thinking of the word as anything other than being common place and descriptive, the same sense in which it is used in *The Hobbit*, Chapter 4. A "breakfast nook" is a standard description of a feature of a kitchen in American home and garden literature.

Answer (score 9):

Yes 'nook' without 'cranny' is fine. From [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nook):

> *Nook*: a corner or recess, especially one offering seclusion or security.

My cat has currently found himself a comfortable nook in the garden to sleep in.

And, most importantly, the term feels perfectly normal, not unusual or archaic to me, a native English speaker. That's the only real test.

Answer (score 4):

[Inglenook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglenook) is a nice word. It means a recess next to a fireplace (`ingle` is an old word for `fire`). It's where people used to put their grannies.

Comment: It would have been rather more fitting if the nooks were where people put their books, grannies being instead stored in the crannies.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: As in "Where's the book nook?" "It's right next to the granny cranny."

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's not necessarily an everyday word, but it's not uncommon - one might describe what you plan as a cosy nook, for example.

Comment: -1. You'll notice that the upvoted answers include authoritative explanation and references, as befits a site that aims to "build a library of detailed answers to every question about English language and usage". Personal opinion is ok, but should be backed up with supporting evidence, otherwise it's simply *commentary*. For further guidance, see [answer], and I also recommend taking the site **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 1):

The term "breakfast nook", meaning an, usually small, area in a kitchen, used for informal eating. Fairly common in American English usage.

Answer (score 0):

Both nook and cranny don’t appear to be much used in contexts different from  the idiomatic expression ***[every nook and cranny](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nook-and-cranny--every)*** according to the following sources:

> Everywhere, as in I've searched for it in every nook and cranny, and I still can't find it. This metaphoric idiom pairs nook, which has meant “an out-of-the-way corner” since the mid-1300s, with cranny, which has meant “a crack or crevice” since about 1440. ***Neither noun is heard much other than in this idiom.***

(Dictionary.com)

And also from [theidioms.com](https://www.theidioms.com/every-nook-and-cranny/),  ***every nook and cranny***:

> The idiom originated in the 14th century and ***it combines ‘nook’, being used from mid-1300s which means – a distant corner, with ‘cranny’ in usage since 1440 which means – a crack or gap.***
>
> The most possible oldest printed record of the idiom can be found in a book named Scottish Scenery by James Cririe, published in 1803.
>
> The other examples of the phrase being used can be traced back to Middle English or Scottish English. The ‘nook’ in the phrase refers to a corner which is out of way and cranny was to point out to any cracks in the walls. ***These nouns are no longer in popular use apart from being used within this phrase.***

Source: theidioms.com

The following [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=every%20nook%20and%20cranny%2Ca%20nook%2Cthe%20nook%2Cone%20nook%2C%20a%20cranny%2C%20the%20cranny%2C%20one%20cranny&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevery%20nook%20and%20cranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20nook%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20nook%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20nook%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20cranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cranny%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20cranny%3B%2Cc0) search  appears to confirm the above assumptions.

Comment: The Google Books search is far too restrictive, because it excludes any noun phrase of the form *<adjective> nook* or *<adjective> cranny*. If you just search for the combined noun phrase and the two simple nouns you see that *nook* occurs far more often than *nook and cranny*.